# Logstash conditional to check if tag exists?

Tags: logstash

Is there any way in logstash to use a conditional to check if a specific tag exists?

For example,

```
grok {
match => [
"message", "Some expression to match|%{GREEDYDATA:NOMATCHES}"
]
```

if NOMATCHES exists Do something.

How do I verify if NOMATCHES tag exists or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just so we're clear: the config snippet you provided is setting a field, not a tag.

Logstash events can be thought of as a dictionary of fields. A field named `tags` is referenced by many plugins via `add_tag` and `remove_tag` operations.

You can check if a tag is set:

```
if "foo" in [tags] {
    ...
}
```

But you seem to want to check if a field contains anything:

```
if [NOMATCHES] =~ /.+/ {
    ...
}
```

The above will check that `NOMATCHES` exists and isn't empty.

[Reference: configuration file overview.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals)

Answer (score 6):

The following test for existence also works [tested in Logstash 1.4.2], although it may not validate non-empty:

```
if [NOMATCHES] {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This checks if the field named NOMATCHES exists. It doesn't look at the value.

Comment: If you use this, be careful if the value of 'NOMATCHES" is boolean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287082/logstash-config-check-if-boolean-field-exists