# Logstash config: check if boolean field exists

Tags: logstash

Using Logstash 1.4.2, I have a field `myfield` that is a boolean value in my JSON document.

To check if it exists (don't care about the boolean value) I used:

```
if[myfield] { ...exists... } else { ...doesn't exist... }
```

The results from testing this conditional statement are:

```
[myfield] does not exist   --> false
[myfield] exists, is true  --> true
[myfield] exists, is false --> false //expected true because the field exists
```

It is checking the boolean value, not its **existence**.

**How can I check that a boolean field exists?**

Comment: Link to github issue https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1867

Answer (score 4):

Kind of lame that it doesn't work right out of the box, but you can hack it like this -- add a string representation of the boolean, compare against the string, and then remove the added field:

```
filter {
   mutate {
     add_field => { "test" => "%{boolean}" }
   }
   if [test] == 'true' or [test] == 'false' {
     // field is present and set right
   } else {
     // field isn't present or set to something other than true/false
   }
   mutate {
     remove_field => [ "test" ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already know that; it's just messy and adds a few extra cpu cycles.

Comment: Seriously, there is no better option??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309096/logstash-check-if-field-exists seems to say that there’s a better way for a Boolean

Answer (score 1):

you can use logstash ruby plugin.

```
filter {  
      ruby {
        code => '
          myfield= event.get("[myfield]")
          if !myfield.nil?
              event.set("[myfield]", "some_value_1")
            else
              event.set("[myfield]", "some_value_2")
            end
        '
      }
    }
```