# Logstash Checking Existence of & Parsing Sub-Field

Tags: logstash

In Logstash I have a JSON payload which I've decoded like so:

```
filter 
{ 
   json 
   { 
     source => "payload" 
     target => "payloadData" 
   }
}
```

Now I want to check if payloadData._extraData exists, and then deserialise that too.

I've tried this method, working from the example given in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309096/logstash-check-if-field-exists):

```
filter 
{ 
   json 
   { 
     source => "payload" 
     target => "payloadData" 
   }
   if [payloadData._extraData] =~ /.+/ 
   { 
       sourcce => "payloadData._extraData"  
       target => "payloadData.extraData" 
   } 
}
```

But it doesn't do anything (no crash, no error message, just doesn't do anything)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct **syntax** is:

```
if [payloadData][_extraData] =~ /.+/   { }
```

**Example input:**

```
{"foo":"bar","spam":"eggs","abc":"xyz","one":"two","three":"four","five":"six","seven":{"eight":"nine"}}
```

**Config:**

```
filter {
    json { source => message }
    if [seven][eight] =~ /.+/ {
        # do something
    }
}
```

Apart from that, the code inside your **if statement** doesn't do anything. You need to specify a filter that should be executed. e.g.:

```
if [payloadData][_extraData] =~ /.+/  { 
   json {
       source => "payloadData[_extraData]"  
       target => "payloadData[extraData]" 
   }
}
```

What do you want to deserialize in your if statement? The first json filter should recognize nested objects.

Comment: Ah, awesome - thanks. I'll give that a shot.  The reason I need the second deserialisation is because it's a message that contains another serialised message. So like ``{"extraData":"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"}``