# If field exists in HTTP, drop Logstash event?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I currently have logstash input for rest API HTTPs webhooked to my Logstash server.

The application sending is sending heartbeats along with the data packets, and I don't need to store those.
So im looking for something like the following in the logstash config:

```
filter {

  if [heartbeat]: {
       drop{}
  }
     
}
```

or something along those lines so that the event that contains that field is dropped

Thanks

Comment: To answer this question we need to know the type of the [heartbeat] field. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309096/logstash-check-if-field-exists) question has some techniques that cover most types. However, a general solution that can handle fields that exist but are nil cannot exist. What is the field type?

Comment: All I see as the value for each is "-" for null, so Im not sure if that would be boolean or not ? I'm seeing the field from target in the XML filter (target.heartbeat) but the value is just "-"

Comment: Then it a string, so the question I linked to answers the question.