# How to create a new field with a substring of another field with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I use filebeat to upload logs to elasticsearch and I wish to use logstash to transform the documents before sending them to ES. I'd like to add a field called my.service that would parse the value of the field log.file.path. Basically, what I want is the following :

```
"log.file.path": "/var/log/myservice.log" 
"my.service": "myservice"
```

I've tried the following filters on logstash but none seems to work :

```
filter {
    if ("" in  [log.file.path]){
        grok {
            match => { "log.file.path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/(?<my.service>).log"}
        }
    }
}


filter {
    if ("" in  [log.file.path]){
        grok {
            match => { "log.file.path" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:my.service}.log"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your if conditions. Are you looking at checking if the string is not empty? If yes, then simply check for `if [log.file.path] {... }`

Comment: @Val I followed this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311149/
I tried with your solution but same result

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the dotted field name, in Logstash nested fields need to be specified by [square brackets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references), just do it this way:

```
filter {
    if [log][file][path] {
        grok {
            match => { "[log][file][path]" => "%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:myservice}.log"}
        }
        mutate {
            rename => {
                "myservice" => "[my][service]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the following JSON document comes in (as a one-liner)

```
{
  "log": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/var/log/myservice.log"
    }
  }
}
```

The output will be

```
{
  "log": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/var/log/myservice.log"
    }
  },
  "my": {
    "service": "myservice"
  }
}
```